# How can I multiply only the cells that contain value?

Tags: excel-2010

I have a Excel spreadsheet with 40 columns but the number of lines for each column varies. I need to multiply these cells by a value. How can I multiply only the cells that contain a value?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends a bit on what you want the result to be if the cell is blank.

If you have a a formula such as "=A1*B1*C1" but A1 could be blank, and you want just the product of B1 and C1 in that case, then you could amend the formula to something like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1), 1, A1)*B1*C1
```

Otherwise it will treat it as zero and the overall product will always be zero.

Answer (score 1):

You could something like:

> =IF(C5="",1,C5) * IF(D5="",1,D5) * IF(E5="",1,E5)

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(C5="",1,C5) * IF(D5="",1,D5) * IF(E5="",1,E5)*IF(C5&D5&E5="",0,1)
```

This is the best formula.
If all of your cells was empty this formula didn't show “1” as the answer. And it will show you zero.